# HTML5 markup with CSS background colours

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to code in HTML5, my `<header>` has 3 sections: e.g. `<div id="topHeader">`, `<nav>` & `<div id="mainHeader">`

The `<topHeader>` and `<nav>` have seperate background colours spanning the width of the viewport (100%).

I would really appreciate some help in the best way to code what I'm trying to do, as I can't figure it out, and also I want to do it the most efficient way.

[image]

It is an existing website, and this is pretty much the way it was done. I would like to wrap the 3 sections into a 'header' tag though. Not sure if I should make the 'header' tag full width?

```
<div id="topHeader">
<div class="contentArea">

    </div><!-- e contentArea -->
</div><!-- e topHeader -->
<div id="mainmenu">
<div class="contentArea">

    </div><!-- e contentArea -->
</div><!-- e menu -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="contentArea">

    </div><!-- e contentArea -->
</div><!-- e header -->



#topHeader {background-color: #9c140a;}
#topHeader .contentArea {width: 990px;}
#mainmenu {background:#b1140b;}
#mainmenu .contentArea {width:990px;}
#header .contentArea {width: 990px;}
```

Comment: `topHeader` and `mainHeader` aren't in HTML5. Are these your own made-up elements? If you're talking about background colors, perhaps you're asking about CSS too?

Comment: Yea sorry, they are div's, I'll see if I can edit the original post.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with example code: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Added some code to original post, hope it's enough.

Comment: Yes you should make it full width as your topheader and nav are both full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have something like what you want, though it's obviously not exactly like your image because it lacks content to fill it up.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="topHeader">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://google.com">Google Link</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="mainHeader">
            <p>Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. Test. Lots 'o Text. </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
.topHeader {
    background-color: DarkRed;
    width:100%;
}

.topHeader a.left {
    margin-left:10%;
}

.topHeader a.right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:10%;
}
nav {
    clear:both;
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
}
.mainHeader {
    width:80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mainHeader p {
    border: dotted;
}

nav a {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej47Q/8/

Comment: Thanks for that Logan. What would be the best way to bring in the text from .topheader & nav inline with .mainHeader, padding? And for HTML5, would it be better to add a 'header' tag as the parent element for all 3 sections?

Comment: I updated to accommodate the inline requirements. As for the header tag... Possibly. You could do something along the lines of what Connor did and apply it to mine.

Answer (score 0):

what about this http://jsfiddle.net/bMySg/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, html{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                font-family:'verdana', sans-serif, arial;
            }

            header{
                width:100%;
                background:#E10000;
                height:300px;
                padding-top:50px; /* height of header:before */
            }

            header:before{
                content:"";
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background:#7C0000;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                z-index:0;
            }

            .top_nav{
                width:75%;
                border:dotted #FFFFFF;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                padding:10px;
                margin-left:12.5%;
                border-top:none;
                border-bottom:none;
            }

            .right{
                float:right;
            }

            .left{
                float:left;
            }

            .head_text{
                font-size:50px;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                padding-top:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="top_nav">
                <a href="#" class="left">Links</a>
                <a href="#" class="right">Links</a>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="head_text">Navigation</h1>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```